# How to remove these warnings

Tags: php, wordpress

I m using Allow PHP in Post and Pages plugin in wordpress by which i integrate a form

**Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): 21 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in ..wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 789**

**Warning: mysql_error(): 21 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in ..wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1102**

The code of my form is here

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("form", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO data (consignor,consignee, conveyance, origin, entry_port, importing_country, container_no, package_no, package_type, product_name, bot_name, quantity, certify, add_declaration, date,treatment, duration_temprature, concentration, add_information, inspector_name, place, name_designation, issue_date)
VALUES
('$_POST[exporter]', '$_POST[importer]', '$_POST[conveyance]', '$_POST[origin]', '$_POST[dpoe]', '$_POST[impcon]', '$_POST[container]', '$_POST[nopk]', '$_POST[tyop]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[botname]', '$_POST[quantity]', '$_POST[certify]', '$_POST[declaration]', '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[treatment]', '$_POST[dutemp]', '$_POST[concen]', '$_POST[adinfo]', '$_POST[insname]', '$_POST[place]', '$_POST[namedesg]', '$_POST[dateissue]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Form Submitted";

mysql_close($con);
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table height ="200px" width="676" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td colspan="7" valign="top" width="676"> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="320">1. Exporter/Consignor (Name & Address)<br/>
<input type="text" name="exporter" />
</td>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" width="356">2. Importer/Consignee (Name & Address)
 <input type="text" name="importer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="320">3. Declared means of conveyance
<input type="text" name="conveyance" /></td>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" width="356">4. Place of Origin<br/>
<input type="text" name="origin" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="320">5. Declared Port of entry<br/>
<input type="text" name="dpoe" /></td>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" width="356">6. Department of Plant Protection of Pakistan To Plant Protection Organization Of (importing country)<br/>
<input type="text" name="impcon" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="320">7. Distinguishing marks/Container No./ Seal No.<br/>
<input type="text" name="container" /></td>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="172">8. No. of Packages<br/>
<input type="text" name="nopk" />
</td>
<td valign="top" width="184">9. Type of packages<br/>
<input type="text" name="tyop" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="221">10. Name of Product<br/>
<input type="text" name="name" /></td>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" width="233">11. Botanical name of plant
<br/>
<input type="text" name="botname" />
</td>
<td colspan="2" valign="top" width="221">12. Quantity<br/>
<input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" valign="top" width="676">13. This is to certify that the plants, plant products or other regulated articles described herein above have been inspected and/ or tested according to appropriate official procedures and are considered to be free from the quarantine pests, specified by the importing contracting party and to conform with the current phytosanitary requirements  of the importing contracting party including those for regulated non-quarantine pests.<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="certify" value="Yes"/> Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="certify" value="No"/> No<br/>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" valign="top" width="676">14. Additional Declaration
<br/>
<textarea name="declaration" cols="40" rows="2">Please limit your response to 200 characters.</textarea><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" valign="top" width="676" bgcolor="grey">
<p align="center"><strong>Disinfestations and / or disinfection treatment </strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="320">15. Date
<br/>
<input type="text" name="date" /></td>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" width="356">16. Treatment<br/>
<input type="text" name="treatment" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="320">17. Duration & Temperature
<br/>
<input type="text" name="dutemp" />
</td>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" width="356">18. Concentration<br/>
<input type="text" name="concen" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" width="320">19. Additional Information
<br/>
<textarea name="adinfo" cols="40" rows="2">Please limit your response to 200 characters.</textarea><br />
</td>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" width="356">20. Name of Inspector<br/>
<input type="text" name="insname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" valign="top" width="240">21. Stamps of Organization
<br></br><br></br>
 </td>
<td rowspan="2" colspan="2" valign="top" width="168">
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong> </strong></p>
<p align="right"><strong>PROGRESSIVE </strong></p>
</td>
<td rowspan="2" colspan="3" valign="top" width="340">23. Place of issue<br/>
<input type="text" name="place" /><br/>
24. Signature__________________________<br/><br></br>
25. Name and designation of authorized officer
<input type="text" name="namedesg" /> <br/><br/>
26. Date <br/>
<input type="text" name="dateissue" /></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" valign="top" width="240">22. No financial liability with respect to this certificate shall attach to department of plant protection or to any of its officers or representatives
<br></br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="221" border="0"></td>
<td width="19"></td>
<td width="80"></td>
<td width="48"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
<td width="47"><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
<td width="137"></td>
<td width="220"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Also it showing the "Form Submitted" on the top of the form and data stored in table. will anybody help me to resolve this problem????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress, you can not call to database using normal mysql system. You need to call the database via the

```
global $wpdb;
```

See this link for more examples. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

***edit***

Try changing your PHP calling code into something like this.

***edit2***

Add some codes to protect against sql attacks. Basically put them into variable and escape it.

```
<?php
//no need to connect & close to db. it's done automatically by wpdb.
// the database MUST be the same with wordpress database. only different tables.
global $wpdb;

//protect your codes from attacks.
@ isset($_POST['exporter']) ? $exporter=$wpdb->escape($_POST['exporter']) : $exporter='';
@ isset($_POST['importer']) ? $importer=$wpdb->escape($_POST['importer']) : $importer='';
@ isset($_POST['conveyance']) ? $conveyance=$wpdb->escape($_POST['conveyance']) : $conveyance='';
//....
@ isset($_POST['dateissue']) ? $dateissue=$wpdb->escape($_POST['dateissue']) : $dateissue='';


if (!$wpdb->insert('data',
                        array(
                            'consignor'=>$exporter
                            ,'consignee'=>$importer
                            ,'conveyance'=>$conveyance
                            //...
                            ,'issue_date'=>$dateissue
                        ))) exit;
else {echo 'Form Submitted';}
?>
```

Comment: so may i replace all db variable with global $wpdb;

Comment: may i integrate HTML form seprately by pure HTML plugin?

Comment: Not sure by what you mean with pure HTML plugin. But the error you have is only because you are trying to access DB via wordpress but not using wpdb. If you use $wpdb for accessing tables, then it will be ok with wordpress. Any HTMLs should be normal.

Comment: Erase the # and make it empty from your form so it becomes.... <form action="" method="post">

Comment: What will be the new location of data from this form?

Comment: what are the @ suppress symbols doing in this? what part of those lines would potentially cause an error to be printed to the page?

Comment: table named as `data` from the example above. You need to create the table manually first in the same database as WP tables. You then use the insert command..... if (!$wpdb->insert('YourCustomTableHere', array(...)));

Comment: @good4m. the suppress symbol just to prevent any warning while trying to get the POST data.

Comment: isnt isset() checking for that?

Comment: @good4m. Yes, the isset suppose to take care of that. I'm just being cautious because this is wordpress, and there might be other plugins trying to hook into the sending / getting process. But, i'm a newbie at plugin development though, I might be wrong. So i just being cautious. :D

Comment: how to integrate this form in wordpress? Plz help me